# TF-IDF for search queries in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, tf-idf

I have implemented machine learning algorithm called MMR, maximal marginal relevance. So basically I would have a query and documents, the algorithm would compute the relevant rate for any query I assign to the documents.

Now, Im using the 20 news groups dataset in tf-idf format, found it here : (http://www.cad.zju.edu.cn/home/dengcai/Data/TextData.html) called fea. I'm a little confused where I am not sure if my query in tf-idf format or not. As The query and documents in my code should be in tf-idf format.

```
function [result,index] = mmr3(query,lambda,docs)

load fea1

fea1=fea1'; 

queries=zeros(1,26214);

queries(query)=1/(size(query,2)); %normalize and set values at appropriate places
query=queries';
A=fea1(:,docs);
%indexes of documents, 18846 different documents
filenames=[docs];

selected=A(:,1);   %select first (most relevant) document, this assumes first document listed
                %is also most relvant to the query

selectedNames=docs(1);  %name of selected document
filenames(docs(1))=[];
rest=A(:,2:end);   %other documents go to variable rest

for i=1:5 %sort top five most relevant documents
MMRmax=-10;                   
for k=1:size(rest,2)      %loop through not yet selected documents
max1=0;
for i=1:size(selected,2) %loop through selected documents
max=sim1(selected(:,i),rest(:,k));       
if max>max1         %look for most similar document from not yet selected and selected
max1=max;         %remeber highest cosine similarity
        end
   end   
   MMR=lambda*(sim1(query,rest(:,k))-(1-lambda)*max1);  %calculate MMR
        if MMR>MMRmax                   %find max MMR
          MMRmax=MMR;
          result(i)=MMRmax;
         selected2=k;
        end
end  ![enter image description here][1]

selected(:,i+1)=rest(:,selected2);      %select document with highest MMR 
selectedNames(i+1)=filenames(selected2);  %name of selected document
rest(:,selected2)=[];                   %delete that document from rest
filenames(selected2)=[];

end
index=selectedNames;
%selectedNames
```

I used the cosine similirity between the query and the document:

```
function [sim2] = sim1(A,B)

sim2=(A'*B)/(norm(A)*norm(B));
if(isnan(sim2))
sim2=0; 
end
```

Here is the input and the output:

```
[result,index]=mmr3([1,2,3],0.2,[1:20])

result= 0.0012   -0.0018    -0.0040    -0.0043    -0.0080

index= 1    10    17    5     20   8
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: My dataset is 18846*26214 vector long. Which is the DocumentID*WordID. I want to have my query in tf-idf format. Although, I'm not quite sure if I am doing it correctly as it supposed to be

Comment: The query should be 26214 long, and go through all the documents in my dataset"fea1", and compute the MMR.